# npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree. How to fix it?

Tags: npm, dependencies, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: 123worx@4.3.0-stg
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~16.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">= 10.x <= 15.x" from @sentry/angular@7.53.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@sentry/angular
npm ERR!   @sentry/angular@"^7.53.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-29T06_17_21_971Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-29T06_17_21_971Z-debug-0.log
```

application not working and app not running ionic serve run the code some errors are coming

Answer (score 0):

From the [@sentry/angular/v/7.57.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/angular/v/7.57.0) documentation, the Angular Version Compatibility section:

> **Important**: This package is not compatible with Angular 16 or newer. Please use `@sentry/angular-ivy` instead.

> This SDK still officially supports Angular 10-15

From the warning, you are using Angular v16. So, try downgrading the Angular to v15 or use [`@sentry/angular-ivy`](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/tree/master/packages/angular-ivy)

> This SDK officially supports Angular 12 to 16 with Angular's new rendering engine, Ivy.